# Django Override of change_view not saving editable list

Tags: django

I have created an override of changelist_view so that after the save button is hit on an editable list in the admin, the editable list is turned off as follows:

```
def changelist_view(self,request,extra_context=None):
    if request.POST.has_key("_save"):
        self.list_editable = []

    return super(InventoryAdmin, self).changelist_view(request,  extra_context=None)
```

Everything is working except the data is not being saved. I am fairly new to Django, but I assume the:

```
super(InventoryAdmin, self).changelist_view(request,  extra_context=None)
```

is supposed to call the original changelist_view function so that the data still gets saved, but it's not working. How do I properly call the original changelist_view function so that it saves the changes to the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are essentially disabling `list_editable` *before* you call the admin's own `changelist_view`, it is skipping the saving of any changes.

See the appropriate code here in the Django docs:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1270

You will see that when `self.editable` is empty, it doesn't do the bulk update.

Comment: From your excellent observation I fixed the problem! Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a proper way of doing this so someone else who had the same problem finds the solution? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> Add 'action_checkbox' in the list_display as the first parameter. For
>   example:

```
self.list_display = ('action_checkbox', ...)
```